# Color buffer misuse in WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

I want to set color for each vertex individually. Here is shaders' code:

```
const VERTEX_SHADER_SOURCE = `
precision mediump float;

attribute vec3 aPosition;
attribute vec4 aColor;

varying vec4 vColor;

uniform mat4 uMatrix;

void main() {
    vColor = aColor;
    gl_Position = uMatrix * vec4(aPosition, 1);
}
`

const FRAGMENT_SHADER_SOURCE = `
precision mediump float;

varying vec4 vColor;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vColor;
}`
```

With this code noting is drawn:

```
const attrLocations = {
    position: gl.getAttribLocation(this.#program, 'aPosition'),
    color: gl.getAttribLocation(this.#program, 'aColor')
}

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.#vertexBuffer)
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(this.#sphere.getVertices()), gl.STATIC_DRAW)
gl.vertexAttribPointer(attrLocations.position, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attrLocations.position)

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.#colorBuffer)
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(this.#drawMode.getColors.call()), gl.STATIC_DRAW)
gl.vertexAttribPointer(attrLocations.color, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0 , 0)
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attrLocations.color)

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.#indicesBuffer)
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(this.#drawMode.getIndices.call()), gl.STATIC_DRAW)
```

If I change **fragment shader** to `gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);`, object is drawn correctly with specified color.

If I change

```
gl.vertexAttribPointer(attrLocations.color, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0 , 0)
```

to

```
gl.vertexAttribPointer(attrLocations.color, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0 , 0)
```

(4 => 3), then object is drawn (but obviously with wrong colors).

But `this.#sphere.getVertices().length / 3 === this.#drawMode.getColors.call().length / 4` is `true`, so each vec3 vertex has vec4 color. For example, there is **100 vertices**, so there will be vertices array with lenght = **300** and colors array with length = **400**.

So, where is the problem?

Comment: Do you use blending? What are the alpha channels of the colors?

Comment: As a question about web code, It would be a good idea to turn that into a runnable snippet. (or even two)

Comment: @Rabbid76 I don't know what is blending, so probably not using it. Color alpha can be 1 or 0.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transparency was ok, but rgb was not. I used yellow-white color, and I coultdn't see it when blue filter was enabled...